# How do i fix this error "Reverse for 'poll_details' with arguments '('',)' not found."

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I mistakenly deleted the db.sqlite3 file in my django project and i tried running `python manage.py migrate` to make a new one but it didnt work. I finally got it to work with `python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb`.

Now when i run the server and try to visit the **homepage** (which used to be populated with **polls** from the former db) I expect to see a blank page, instead I get this error:

> Reverse for 'poll_details' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['poll/(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)$']

This is my index view which renders the index page

```
def index(request):
    user = request.user

    if user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("poll:home"))

    latest_questions = Question.objects.order_by("-pub_date")[:10]  
    return render(request, "poll/index.html", {"questions": latest_questions})
```

This is index template

```
{% block body %}
    <h1> Polls </h1>

    <ol>
        {% for question in questions %}

            {% empty %}
            <p> There are no polls yet</p>

            <li>{{ question }}</li> 
            <a href="{% url 'poll:poll_details' question.id %}"> View Poll </a>
        {% endfor %}
    </ol>
{% endblock %}
```

The question model

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField("date-asked", default=datetime.datetime.now())
    description = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="questions_asked")
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    likers = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, blank=True, related_name="liked_polls")

    def toggle_status(self):
            if self.is_active:
                self.is_active = False
            else:
                self.is_active = True

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.question_text}"
```

Comment: Share your `Question` model.

Comment: I've shared the Question model

Comment: Please show polls/urls.py

Comment: That is the full model? You did not define a primary key?

Comment: Yes. I didn’t. I thought every model have an id field by default which serves as the primary key

Answer (score -1):

Create a check in `Django templates` like this:

```
{% block body %}
    <h1> Polls </h1>

    <ol>
        {% if questions %}
            {% for question in questions %}
                <li>{{ question }}</li> 
                <a href="{% url 'poll:poll_details' question.id %}"> View Poll </a>
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <p> nothing to show </p>
        {% endif %}
    </ol>
{% endblock %}
```

when there are no searches in the database, it may display a message

*Built-in [template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#if) tags and filters*